# Why is $n\choose k$ where $k>n$ impossible?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

suppose there is 2 choices $A, B$ and would like to pick from these 2 randomly for 3 times.

possible outcome? (combination?):

AAA
AAB
ABB
BBB

is there a mathematical expression for (in my concept), n Choose k where k is larger than n? I feel like this is not correct for sure but I'm lost in direction. any hints?

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition

Comment: ABA is not different from AAB? In that case, you basically have a set of $n$ elements and you want to pick $k$ of these elements, *possibly with repeats* and *only counting how many times each number occurs*. See the stars-and-bars method over [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) with examples. In your case, the answer is $4$ because for $k=3,n=2$, the answer is $\binom{2+3-1}{3} = \binom{4}{3} = 4$.

Answer (score 2):

In the conventional definition of $\binom nk$, we are choosing $k$ elements from a set of $n$ *without replacement*. Which is to say, once you've chosen the A, you're not allowed to choose it again. If you have only A and B to pick from, and you want to choose three elements in this way, then clearly it's impossible. So $\binom 23=0$.

If you are choosing *with* replacement, i.e. we allow repeating the same element, then a priori the binomial coefficients $\binom nk$ do not count that. It turns out you can use them anyways, using the argument colloquially known as [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)). In the case of choosing three out of two available letters, we get $\binom{3+2-1}{2-1}$ (where the ${}-1$ is part of the formula, and the $3$ and the $2$ come from the numbers in the problem).